commutative algebra in correspondences from associative algebra
Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a symmetric monoidal category with finite direct sums, and $A$ an associative algebra in $\mathcal{C}$. Let $\mathcal{C}_{\operatorname{corr}}$ be the (1-)category of correspondences: It has the same object as $\mathcal{C}$ and morphisms $X \to Y$ are given by diagrams
$$X \leftarrow Z \rightarrow Y$$
in $\mathcal{C}$. $\mathcal{C}_{\operatorname{corr}}$ has a natural symmetric monoidal structure coming from the one on $\mathcal{C}$.
Now define the following commutative algebra in $\mathcal{C}$: its underlying object is $A$, and the multiplication map $A^{\otimes n} \to A$ is given by the correspondence:
$$A \leftarrow \bigoplus_{\sigma \in \Sigma_n} \sigma^*(A^{\otimes n}) \rightarrow A^{\otimes n}$$
where the left arrow is the composition of the automorphism $\sigma$ with the multiplication map, and the right arrow the direct sum of the maps $\sigma^*(A^{\otimes n}) \xrightarrow{\sim} A^{\otimes n}$ given by the symmetric monoidal structure on $\mathcal{C}$.
Does this constructtion make sense? does it have a name? Is it a special case of some general free algebra functor?
